# REST request between Postgresql and Flask

Tags: python, postgresql, rest, flask

I'm starting with RESTApi and Flask, I'm requesting a Postgresql table and I'm trying to factorise my code to have a unique request with my table name as an argument

```
df_srcstatistiquedata = pd.read_sql_query('select * from "srcstatistiquedata"', con=engine)
df_srcstatistiquesuppression = pd.read_sql_query('select * from "srcstatistiquesuppression"', con=engine)
df_srcentete = pd.read_sql_query('select * from "srcentete"', con=engine)


@app.route('/api/srcstatistiquedata', methods=("POST", "GET"))
def get_srcstatistiquedata_json():
    data_json_srcstatistiquedata = df_srcstatistiquedata.to_json()
    return data_json_srcstatistiquedata

@app.route('/api/srcstatistiquesuppression', methods=("POST", "GET"))
def get_srcstatistiquesuppression_json():
    data_json_srcstatistiquesuppression = df_srcstatistiquesuppression.to_json()
    return data_json_srcstatistiquesuppression

@app.route('/api/srcentete', methods=("POST", "GET"))
def get_srcentete_json():
    data_json_srcentete = df_srcentete.to_json()
    return data_json_srcentete
```

Here is my new code, I have an error 404 when I try to request(GET) my html page 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/stat_data' from my browser or Postman.

```
dico = {
    'stat_data': "srcstatistiquedata",
    'stat_suppr': "srcstatistiquesuppression",
    'en_tete': "srcentete"
}

def get_table(table_name):
    query = 'select * from "${table_name}"'
    return pd.read_sql_query(query, con=engine)



@app.route('/api/${table_name}', methods=("POST", "GET"))
def get_table_json():
    parametre_post = request.args.get('table')
    print(parametre_post)
    data_generique = get_table(dico[parametre_post])
    return df_generique.to_json()
```

What do I need to modify in order to get my data from my different tables ? Thank you

Comment: `/api/${table_name}` -> `/api/<table_name>`, `def get_table_json():` -> `def get_table_json(table_name):`

Comment: Also, `query = 'select * from "${table_name}"'` -> `f'query = 'select * from {table_name}'`

Comment: Last thing: `methods=("POST", "GET")` -> `methods=("GET", )`